# CollectionViewSource and Combobox

Tags: wpf, combobox, collectionviewsource

I have a problem with a binding.
In my application which is a wpf app, I have a Cache class which hold some common data. The data are stored in observablecollections.

In my app when I use the Cache data in bindings I use collectionviewsource with the source property set to the cache observablecollection.
The problem occurs when I open my common data edit window, edit something, save and then reload the cache by clearing the observable collections and re-add the common data.
The comboboxes I have bound to collectionviewsources doesn't refresh the selected item. 
But if I open up the combobox I see the correct value in the drop down list. And that item is the one that is selected.

How is this possible?
See my screen dump.
The updated value should be "MASKINMANSKAnicke" but the selected item shows the old value "MASKINMANSKAolle".

[image]

EDITED:

I "solved" it by inherit the combobox and at selectionchanged to a call to UpdateLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call to UpdateLayout on combobox to refresh the GUI. See post.

Answer (score 0):

```
          <ComboBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" />
```

Comment: Yes I have that setting to true. It has nothing todo with this issue.